# Python Tornado WebSocket: not working on second network interface

Tags: python, networking, websocket, server, tornado

I have WebSocket server and client app running on the same physical server. The server has two network interfaces and two IP addresses. When I run WebSocket server/client on first IP it works perfect. Bit it dosn't work on second.

Server:

```
port = 8080
ip1 = '192.168.100.11'
ip2 = '10.110.50.11'
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(port, ip1)
```

With second IP I got the following errors on client:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <bound method WebSocketClient.keep_alive of <__main__.WebSocketClient instance at 0x7efc93d912d8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 1229, in _run
    return self.callback()
  File "./client_rt_websocket.py", line 70, in keep_alive
    self.ws.write_message("sendHeartbeat 1")
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1214, in write_message
    return self.protocol.write_message(message, binary=binary)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 870, in write_message
    raise WebSocketClosedError()
```

It seems like socket is closed and client cannot write message.

Comment: Perhaps you need to setup port forwarding with your router?

Comment: What are you doing to get that error?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by restarting problematic network interface:

```
ifconfig eno2 down
ifconfig eno2 up
```